# What's wrong with this sql as following

Tags: sql, oracle

sql:

```js
SELECT count(TRANSFER_REQUEST_ID) count
FROM XXSTT_TRANSFER_REQUESTS
WHERE (OVERALL_STATUS = 'Approved' AND LAST_UPDATE_DATE < CASE
                                                         WHEN #{date} <= DATE '2017-09-10'
                                                           THEN #{date}
                                                         ELSE DATE '2017-09-10')
                                                              OR (CREATION_DATE > DATE '2017-09-10' AND
                                                                 OVERALL_STATUS = 'Completed' AND
                                                                 LAST_UPDATE_DATE < #{date})
ORDER BY CREATION_DATE DESC;
```

When i run this sql, error will accur with message

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

my select condition is like that if the LAST_UPDATE_DATE larger than '2017-09-10' then use this date and else use the input date

Comment: In the case-when syntax, shouldn't you use END at the end of the statement? I use aws Redshift that is oracle and syntax is similar, I am expecting END https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

Comment: I don't know witch keyword i missed

Comment: Thank you, @MiloBellano  I miss keyword "END" in the case...when clause, i'm careless ...

Comment: AWS redshift is PostgreSQL is it not

Comment: Hahaha yes! I poor me in coffee need, I had in mind postgres while saying oracle, well, I'll go back to sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As identified by [@MiloBellano in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47153210/whats-wrong-with-this-sql-as-following#comment81255979_47153210):

```
SELECT count(TRANSFER_REQUEST_ID) count
FROM   XXSTT_TRANSFER_REQUESTS
WHERE  (   OVERALL_STATUS = 'Approved'
       AND LAST_UPDATE_DATE < CASE
                              WHEN #{date} <= DATE '2017-09-10'
                              THEN #{date}
                              ELSE DATE '2017-09-10'
                              END                      -- This is missing
       )
OR     (   CREATION_DATE > DATE '2017-09-10'
       AND OVERALL_STATUS = 'Completed'
       AND LAST_UPDATE_DATE < #{date}
       )
ORDER BY CREATION_DATE DESC;
```